# NIR.subtract is not a function

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, ndvi, sentinel-2, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to calculate Kernal NDVI (kNDVI) and the code keeps giving me this error.
The link to the code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/24e8503ec2f264d0ffe0ba1bfe4c6353

```
/// adding shapefile to the map

Map.addLayer(Etosha);

/// Dates of Interest
var start = ee.Date('2021-03-01');
var finish = ee.Date('2021-03-31');

// creating Image Collection
var S2A = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
.filterBounds(Etosha)
.filterDate(start,finish)
.filterMetadata('Cloud_Cover','Less_Than',30);


/// Selecting the Bands
var image = S2A.mean();
var RED = S2A.select ('B4');
var NIR = S2A.select ('B8');

var addKNDVI = function(image){
  
  // Compute D2 a rename it to d2
  var D2 = NIR.subtract(RED).pow(2)
  .select([0],['d2']);
  
  // Gamma, defined as 1/sigmaˆ2
  var gamma = ee.Number(4e6).multiply(-2.0);
  
  // Compute kernel (k) and KNDVI
  var k = D2.divide(gamma).exp();
  var kndvi = ee.Image.constant(1)
  .subtract(k).divide(ee.Image.constant(1).add(k))
  .select([0],['knd']);
  return image.addBands(kndvi);
  
}
 
var kndvi = addKNDVI(image).select('kndvi');

Map.addLayer(kndvi);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NIR and RED are collections, not images.  Do the select inside the function on each individual image instead of on the whole collection.